# Analytic PDF for the joint distribution between dependent and independent normal distributions

Tags: probability

Consider $x\sim N(0,1)$ and  $y\sim N(0,\sqrt{2})$, where
$N(a,b)$ means a normal distribution with mean $a$ and variance $b$. $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Is possible to obtain the PDF of the distribution of
$\mathbb{P}(x,y,x-y)$?

If this simplifies the possible response, I am interested in computing probability of having
$x>0$, $y>0$, and $x-y>0$.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: yes, they are. I added that to the question. Thanks

Comment: Use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent to get the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$, then find $P(X>0,Y>0,X-Y>0)$ by integrating your joint pdf over an appropriate region in the $xy-$plane

Comment: You're right, @MatthewPilling. Thanks. I'm not sure, but if you write your hint as answer that's OK for me.